# Analysis of data types usage in databases

Tags: oracle, database-design

I was wondering if there is any analysis on the usage of different data types used in databases? I mean, an analysis that ranks the usage of different data-types, for instance:

Most used

1. DECIMAL
2. DATE
   ....etc in databases (mainly Oracle) ?

If it also includes the types of operations that normally run on this data it would be awesome.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what do you need those statistics for?

Answer (score 0):

Might not be entirely what you are looking for, but its a starter-

```
SQL> select data_type, round(avg(data_length),4) avg_length,round(avg(density),4) 
avg_density
from user_tab_cols
group by data_type;

DATA_TYPE               AVG_LENGTH         AVG_DENSITY
------------           -------------       -------------
DATE                   7                    0.3369 
TIMESTAMP(6)           11                   1 
RAW                    32                   1 
NUMBER                 22                   0.2429 
CHAR                   1.0776               0.254 
VARCHAR2               34.9129              0.3941 
TIMESTAMP(3)           11                   0.2408
```